# Use past publish dates in Blogger's permalinks

Tags: blogger, permalinks

Until yesterday, the blogger used the current date in permalink, despite the custom publish date I set.
For example, when I was setting a (past) publish date like Feb 18, 2019, the permalink was `https://myBlogName.blogspot.com/2019/02/whatever-the-post-title-is.html`. Today, when I try to set the same past publish date, is been replaced in permalink with the current one like `https://myBlogName.blogspot.com/2021/07/whatever-the-post-title-is.html`.

Is there an announcement from Google for that?

Did Google stop supporting the use of past publish dates?

Comment: this should be posted in the [Blogger community](https://support.google.com/blogger/community?hl=en), and I just noticed this, maybe it is just a bug

Comment: @Bouh. I did it and got no answers. Thanks for the bug suspicion though.